# Why does 'sort' ignore special characters, like the asterisk?

Tags: sorting

I thought that `sort` would sort common prefixes together but that doesn't always happen. Take this input for example:

```
AT0S*eightieths
AT0S*eyetooth's
AT*ad
AT*Ad
AT*AD
AT*Eydie
AT*eyed
ATF*adv
ATF*ATV
ATF*edify
ATF*Ediva
ATFKT*advocate
ATFKTNK*advocating
ATFKT*outfought
ATFKTS*advocates
ATHT*whitehead
ATHT*Whitehead
AT*id
AT*I'd
AT*Ito
AT*IUD
ATJ*adage
ATNXNS*attention's
ATNXNS*attenuation's
ATNXNS*autoignition's
AT*oat
AT*OD
AT*outweigh
AT*owed
ATP0K*idiopathic
ATP*adobe
ATT*wighted
ATT*witted
ATT*wooded
AT*UT
AT*Uta
AT*wowed
AT*Wyatt
ATX*atishoo
```

After `sort`, I'd expect all the `AT*` to end up in one chunk but when you run this data through `sort`, the output `==` input. Why is that? I'm not specifying any option to ignore non-alphabetic characters or anything. Just `sort dict > out`.

My version of `sort` comes from `coreutils 8.5-1ubuntu3`.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe an alias somewhere?

Comment: I can confirm i'm having the exact same problem too under debian, but with commas, it's driving me crazy. How can you sort csvs when it behaves like this by default?

Comment: @Owl Use the proper tool for the job: xsv or csvkit.

Comment: @aaron digulla sort is the proper tool for the job, it's just that it's default behaviour is non standard for some distributions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
sort --version-sort filename
```

This preserves the natural order of numbers.

Comment: +1 That works but why? There are only a few single-digits in the text.

Comment: Works without needing to change the environment, +1

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I suspect that it treats the strings in version sort as nearly the dumbest way to sort things, so it ignores locale and only handles numbers in a special way.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my csv data.

Answer (score 25):

Setting LC_ALL=C restored the traditional sorting order in my case. Package: coreutils
Version: 8.5-1ubuntu3

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: `LANG=C` also works. What puzzles me: `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`; why is `*` still treated special??

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` is the setting that's specific to `sort`, etc.

Comment: works for me in Raspbian//Pixel... the sort 'annoyance' ignoring the special chars was killig me... thanks.

Comment: no need to `export` or even set local and possibly mess with something else. Just set it in the call to sort: `LC_ALL=C sort`. E.g. `echo -e 'a\n*\n*b\nc' | LC_ALL=C sort`, LC_ALL will not be changed outside the call to sort

Answer (score 6):

To provide a simple answer based on others' comments, that doesn't change your environment:

```sh
input_program | LC_COLLATE=C sort | output_program
```

or

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort < input_file > output_file
```

or combinations thereof.

Comment: For more info on what LC_COLLATE is and how to change it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361021/26152

Answer (score 2):

Version: *sort (GNU coreutils) 8.26*

I do it inline:

```
LANG=C sort FILE
```

Or by function (changes the original file):

```
dosort() { local file="$*"; LANG=C sort ${file} -o ${file}.swp; mv ${file}.swp ${file}; cat ${file} ;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected for me (on cygwin).

`sort input > output` results in

```
AT*AD
AT*Ad
AT*Eydie
AT*I'd
AT*IUD
AT*Ito
AT*OD
AT*UT
AT*Uta
AT*Wyatt
AT*ad
AT*eyed
AT*id
AT*oat
AT*outweigh
AT*owed
AT*wowed
AT0S*eightieths
AT0S*eyetooth's
ATF*ATV
ATF*Ediva
ATF*adv
ATF*edify
ATFKT*advocate
ATFKT*outfought
ATFKTNK*advocating
ATFKTS*advocates
ATHT*Whitehead
ATHT*whitehead
ATJ*adage
ATNXNS*attention's
ATNXNS*attenuation's
ATNXNS*autoignition's
ATP*adobe
ATP0K*idiopathic
ATT*wighted
ATT*witted
ATT*wooded
ATX*atishoo
```

Is sort aliased to something?  try `\sort`

Also

> The locale specified by the
>   environment affects sort order. Set
>   LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort
>   order that uses native byte values

Comment: No alias. Must be some ubuntu/debian specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sort you can use `--dictionary-order`:

```
NAME
       sort - sort lines of text files

SYNOPSIS
       sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       sort [OPTION]... --files0-from=F

DESCRIPTION
       Write sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.

       With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.  Ordering options:

       -b, --ignore-leading-blanks
              ignore leading blanks

       -d, --dictionary-order
              consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters
```

Comment: Might be documented but does not work for me (Fedora 36 -> coreutils-9.0-9.fc36.x86_64).  The `LC_ALL` hack does.
`echo -ne "- a\n+ a\n- b\n+ b\n" | sort -d` Still shows unsorted lines